# Non binding section in a legal agreement?

Tags: contract-law

Is there a concept or known word to describe a text in a legal agreement that is not binding.

We would like to annotate an agreement with sections that explain the intended consequences without themselves being the basis for it.

**Example:**

One part of the agreement says:

> Service A can be cancelled with 6 months notice.

Another part says

> Service B can be cancelled with 12 months notice.
>   **Note that service A only has 6 months notice.**

Say I change the first part to be only 4 months notice for service A. but I forget to update the added note in the second section.

A **workaround** being non specific:

> Note that service A may have a shorter notice.

Comment: Yes. There is such an idea and there are terms for this.

Comment: Note that the Service A notice requirement may be different. The Service A notice requirement is defined in A.1.ii. (or wherever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask your pay lawyer about this. You might make the whole contract void by messing up the notices.

You might, however, use another workaround that you can't easily mess up:

- Put all cancelation notice times in one paragraph and always refer to "cancelation notice as defined in X.Y"
- Don't include the actual numbers in the contract but the ToS

  - "The service(es) can be canceled with a notice as defined in the Terms and Services." [which are not part of the contract and can be changed much faster!]